# Spark driver program launching in `cluster` mode failed in a weird way

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to Spark. Now I encountered a problem: when I launch a program in a standalone spark cluster while command line:

```
./spark-submit --class scratch.Pi --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 5g --name pi --driver-memory 5g --driver-java-options "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" --master spark://bx-42-68:7077 hdfs://bx-42-68:9000/jars/pi.jar
```

It will throws following error:

```
15/01/28 19:48:51 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/01/28 19:48:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverClient' on port 59290.
Sending launch command to spark://bx-42-68:7077
Driver successfully submitted as driver-20150128194852-0003
... waiting before polling master for driver state
... polling master for driver state
State of driver-20150128194852-0003 is FAILED
```

Master of cluster outputs following log:

```
15/01/28 19:48:52 INFO Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
15/01/28 19:48:52 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20150128194852-0003 on worker worker-20150126133948-bx-42-151-26286
15/01/28 19:48:55 INFO Master: Removing driver: driver-20150128194852-0003
15/01/28 19:48:57 INFO Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@bx-42-68:59290 got disassociated, removing it.
15/01/28 19:48:57 INFO Master: akka.tcp://driverClient@bx-42-68:59290 got disassociated, removing it.
15/01/28 19:48:57 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://driverClient@bx-42-68:59290] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/01/28 19:48:57 INFO LocalActorRef: Message [akka.remote.transport.ActorTransportAdapter$DisassociateUnderlying] from Actor[akka://sparkMaster/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://sparkMaster/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FsparkMaster%4010.16.42.68%3A48091-16#-1393479428] was not delivered. [9] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

And the corresponding worker for launching driver program outputs:

```
15/01/28 19:48:52 INFO Worker: Asked to launch driver driver-20150128194852-0003
15/01/28 19:48:52 INFO DriverRunner: Copying user jar hdfs://bx-42-68:9000/jars/pi.jar to /data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/driver-20150128194852-0003/pi.jar
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
15/01/28 19:48:55 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/opt/apps/jdk-1.7.0_60/bin/java" "-cp" "/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/work/driver-20150128194852-0003/pi.jar:::/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/../conf:/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar:/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" "-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" "-Dspark.executor.memory=5g" "-Dspark.akka.askTimeout=10" "-Dspark.rdd.compress=true" "-Dspark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" "-Dspark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" "-Dspark.app.name=YANL" "-Dspark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" "-Dspark.jars=hdfs://bx-42-68:9000/jars/pi.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://bx-42-68:7077" "-Dspark.storage.memoryFraction=0.6" "-Dakka.loglevel=WARNING" "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" "-Xms5120M" "-Xmx5120M" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@bx-42-151:26286/user/Worker" "scratch.Pi"
15/01/28 19:48:55 WARN Worker: Driver driver-20150128194852-0003 exited with failure
```

My `spark-env.sh` is:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/opt/apps/scala-2.11.5
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/apps/jdk-1.7.0_60
export SPARK_HOME=/data11/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=`hostname -f`
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=`hostname -f`
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=10.16.42.68:2181,10.16.42.134:2181,10.16.42.151:2181,10.16.42.150:2181,10.16.42.125:2181 -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/spark"
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=43g
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=22
```

And my `spark-defaults.conf` is:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
spark.executor.memory            20g
spark.rdd.compress               true
spark.storage.memoryFraction     0.6
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
```

**However**, when I launch the program with **`client`** mode with following command, it works fine.

```
./spark-submit --class scratch.Pi --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 5g --name pi --driver-memory 5g --driver-java-options "-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" --master spark://bx-42-68:7077 /data11/pi.jar
```

Comment: The master cluster output is telling you that the tcp connection used to communicate one of the nodes got dropped somehow. There should be a log for the worker that had the driver drop. Check there for a specific error.

Comment: The corresponding worker's log is posted up there, I can't figure why, can you be more specific, please? @suiterdev

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. It is not very helpful. Have you confirmed the usual things, iptables and hosts mapped in /etc/hosts for each node? Sometimes DNS does not do the trick, you might try plugging the IP addresses into the spark-env.sh for the nodes. Beyond that, some searching indicates lots of the driver disassociation errors, but for various reasons. Sometimes bugs, sometimes environment variables. To test, turn off iptables on the nodes and set selinux to permissive or off if you haven't. Sorry I can't be more helpful with the worker log failure.

Comment: @Neal Try updating your spark version to 1.3.1. Since spark 1.3.1 supports standalone cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it works in "client" mode and not in "cluster" mode is because there is no support for "cluster" mode in a standalone cluster.(mentioned in the spark documentation).

```
Alternatively, if your application is submitted from a machine far from the worker machines (e.g. locally on your laptop), it is common to use cluster mode to minimize network latency between the drivers and the executors.
```

> Note that cluster mode is currently not supported for standalone
>   clusters, Mesos clusters, or python applications.

If you look at "Submitting Applications" section in spark documentation, it is clearly mentioned that the support for cluster mode is not available in standalone clusters.

Reference link : http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html

Go to above link and have a look at "Launching Applications with spark-submit" section.

Think it will help. Thanks.

Comment: As of today (24-Apr-2015), the documentation no longer mention such limitation. [http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/submitting-applications.html](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/submitting-applications.html). I guess it implies it is supporting now

Comment: @user2829759 That is mentioned in spark version 1.2.0 and you are pointing it to spark version 1.3.1. Also the OP is using spark 1.2.0 not 1.3.1. Check out the link mentioned in my answer for spark 1.2.0.

Comment: @user2829759 Yeah, that could be a possible solution. Thanks for pointing it out :).